# is there any word add-in that can do this?

Tags: c#, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I'm looking for a word addin that can allow the user to create a triple list of words and associations and show a line under words or phrases that have matches in the list.

For example, lets say I write the word "canine"

In the addin I would set canine up as an alert word and connect it to dog... then the word dog would be connected to all dog breeds ( a list).

Also other words could be connect to dog.

So essentially there would be the middle connect words or phrases.... the words that show up like a misspelled word does... and then the words which shows up on the menu when the user right clicks (like the dog breeds).

I was thinking about writing such a program myself... but I don't know visual basic or c#... so I'm hopinh theres something out there that can do this.

Thank you to anyone with the heart to respond. :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is almost certainily [SmartTags](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/284927). This is a built-in feature to word which can be customized. You might have seen these in action if you type in someones name in Microsoft Word and a purple dotted line appears under it. This is smart tags in action.

I'm afraid to use these for what you are looking for you will almost certainly have to do some code. However a lot of it appears XML based so it shouldn't be too hard. Take a look at the [following site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa163627%28v=office.10%29.aspx) for some examples.